# Handling CSRF token when working with Django Rest Framework JWT

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, django-csrf, django-rest-framework-jwt

Having the JWT token required for every request to the API, should I keep CSRF protection? Considering no one has access to other's jwtoken, of course.

If yes, how could I get the csrf token since I don't use django templates (I'm using Vue separately).

If not, is it ok to completely delete the CSRF middleware from settings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing the JWT in localStorage, you are not vulnerable to CSRF because localStorage cannot be accessed across domains. You should be aware, however, that there is debate as to whether it is wise to keep a JWT in localStorage since it can be stolen if you fall victim to XSS. The alternative is to store the token in a httpOnly cookie, in which case you must use CSRF protection.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Django, `csrf_token` will be in your site cookies.
You can access it from cookies and pass it along with the request.

Comment: I'm not using django templates at all, I don't have cookies or sessions from django's middlewares. The authentication is simply just taking the jwt token from (default: `api-token-auth`) and storing it into localStorage for further requests, that's all, no cookies involved. But now when I'm using django-rest-framework views to post data, it requires me that csrf token (isn't jwt token enough already?)